# Mechanism for conversion of imide to ester with NaH

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

> [image: Conversion of ethyl 3-hydroxy-2-oxo-3-phenylpiperidine-1-carboxylate to 1-benzyl-2-oxo-3-phenylpiperidin-3-yl ethyl carbonate]

What is the mechanism of this reaction? My proposed mechanism is shown below, would it work?

[image: proposed mechanism]

Comment: Sodium hydride is a non-nucleophilic base.

Comment: Joe kent: Try forming the alkoxide with NaH first and then transfer the CO2Et group either intra- or intermolecularly. The amide ion that is left is ready for alkylation. Try it and see what you get.

Comment: Not sure the sodium hydride is intended as,a nucleophile.  It could react with the benzoyl bromide.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

NaH is a strong base but a bad nucleophile. This is one possible mechanism.

Comment: Correct about NaH but I can’t agree with that SN2...